# Angular UI Bootstrap tab select vs ng-click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

[Angular UI Bootstrap Tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tabs) support a "select" parameter.

> An optional expression called when tab is activated. Supports $event in template for expression.

What does select offer over ng-click?

Answer (score 0):

Like shown in the documentation, you are able to select a tab external, e.g. via a seperate button. In this case, the ng-click wouldn't work, unlike the select parameter.